# Flask Sqlalchemy and Marshmallow return Array in Quotes like "[Array]“

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I need your help

When I want to return an array with SQLAlchemy from my flask-backendserver with a MariaDb, it is always in quotes like this -> "[{obj}, {obj}, {obj}]".

my query:

```
units = Unit.query.all()
print(units) --> [<Unit 1>, <Unit 2>, <Unit 3>, <Unit 4>, <Unit 5>, <Unit 6>, <Unit 7>, <Unit 8>, <Unit 9>, <Unit 10>]
result = units_schema.dumps(units).data
return {"msg": result}
```

But my result looks like this:

```
{
"msg": "[{\"unit_name\": \"Name1\", \"unit_id\": \"ID_1\"},{\"unit_name\": \"Name2\", \"unit_id\": \"ID_2\"}]"
}
```

My Classmodel:

```
class Unit(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "unit_table"
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
unit_name = db.Column(db.String(40))
unit_id = db.Column(db.String(40), unique=True)
created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=(func.now()))
last_updated = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), onupdate=func.now())

def __str__(self):
    return self.unit_id

@classmethod
def find_by_unit_id(cls, unit_id):
    return cls.query.filter_by(unit_id=unit_id).first()

admin.add_view(ModelView(Unit, db.session))

class UnitSchema(marshmallow.ModelSchema):
id = field_for(Unit, 'unit_id', load_only=True)
created_at = field_for(Unit, 'created_at', load_only=True)
last_updated = field_for(Unit, 'last_updated', load_only=True)
class Meta:
    model = Unit


unit_schema = UnitSchema()
units_schema = UnitSchema(many=True)
```

What am I missing? With other queries it works as expected.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error:

```
result = units_schema.dumps(units).data
```

should be:

```
result = units_schema.dump(units).data # dump NOT dumps
```